# Floating point core dumped problem with c program

Tags: c

I was trying to make a small program to try and find the smallest positive num that is evenly divisible bu all of the num from 1 to 20. The line that I wrote are these, but I am taking a "Floating point exception (core dumped) and can't understand the problem... May someone helps me ?

```
int main()
{
  int flag=0, divideCheck, modNum=1;
  long num= 1;

  while(flag<=20)
  {
    divideCheck = num % modNum;
    if (divideCheck == 0)
    {
      flag += 1;
      modNum += 1;

    }else{
      num += 1;
      flag = 0;
      modNum = 0;
    }
  }
  printf("\nThe smallest number is: %li",num);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: `modNum = 0;` and then next round, and then division by zero

Comment: yeaahh I just realize that too !! thank you very much @user12986714 !! how can I close the question answers ? Thanks again

Comment: post an answer to your own question. Someone else may make the same mistake

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I made in the else statement the modNum=0 and in the next loop, the divide was wrong... So I was taking the core dumped error. All I had to do was to change modNum=0 with modNum=1 in the else statement.

Comment: It say that I will be able to do this in 2 days... I will forget too thank you again @user12986714 :) !